# Xamarin Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin.android

Fiz a instalação do Visual Studio Community 2015 e do Xamarin, porém não estou conseguindo emular minhas aplicações, ocorre o seguinte erro durante a compilação:

> 1>:Deployment failed
>
> 1>Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory
>
> 1>   at
>   Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken
>   token)
>
> 1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> 1>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>
> 1>Deployment failed because of an internal error: No such file or
>   directory
>
> 1>InternalError

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema?

Comment: Veja https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56680/deployment-failed-internal-error

Comment: Olá veja o post [adbexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791582/mono-androidtools-adbexception-no-such-file-or-directory-i-am-lost) se te ajuda.